# Proximity Alerts not working,I've made a simple android app with google maps api v2

Tags: android, location, alert, proximity, alerts

Proximity Alert doesn't show up at all.Sorry for the long code.I've been working on this for more than a day now still cant find a solution.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm new to Programming and android and I'm working on a Location alarm(Proximity based alarm)

**This is the function that calls Proximity alert**

```
       private void dispdist(LatLng dest)
       {
      float[] distance=new float[3];
      try {
        double lat2 = dest.latitude;
        double lon2 = dest.longitude;
        double lat1 = mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude();
        double lon1 = mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude();
        //t1.setText(dest.toString());
         Location destination;
        destination=new Location();
        destination.setLatitude(dest.latitude);
        destination.setLongitude(dest.longitude);
        location.distanceBetween(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, distance);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Distance: " 
       + distance[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        drawCircle(dest);
        addProximityAlerts(destination.getLatitude()
        , destination.getLongitude());
       } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Android: ", "Marker drag end");
       }
       }
```

**So this is my function to fire up proximity alerts**

```
    private void addProximityAlerts(double latitude, double longitude)
  {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
        getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
             if(prox==false)
                 {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Into add 
                //  proximity",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                 // .show();
           PendingIntent proximityIntent = 
                      PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    //"Addedproximity",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude,
                    longitude, 50, 60000, proximityIntent);

                       IntentFilter filter = new 
                              IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    //  "added proximity1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);

              prox=true;

             }
              else
             {
                 Intent anIntent=new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
                 PendingIntent operation =
                         PendingIntent
                .getBroadcast(getApplicationContext()
                  , 0 , anIntent, 0);
                 locationManager.removeProximityAlert(operation);
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
               //"Removed last proximity alert",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                //.show();
                 prox=false;
                 addProximityAlerts(latitude,longitude);

                  }}
```

**Manifest**

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission 
            android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"       
    />
<uses-permission  android:name=
                     "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name=
       "com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
 <uses-permission android:name=
       "com.example.androidmapv2ex.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
  <!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
   -->
      <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
     <uses-permission 
      android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" 
       />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
     <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <receiver
            android:name=".ProximityIntentReceiver">
        </receiver>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>

     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    </application>

       </manifest>
```

**ProximityIntentReciever**

```
    public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Into Recieve",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    if (entering) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
    }
    else {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
    }
    Toast.makeText(context,"Into Recieve1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)   

        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
     null, 0);

    Notification notification = createNotification();
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,
            "Proximity Alert!", "Entered",pendingIntent);

     notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }

   private Notification createNotification() {
    Notification notification = new Notification();

    notification.icon = R.drawable.dest_ic;
    notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
    notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
    notification.ledOffMS = 1500;

    return notification;
        }

          }
```

Comment: Do anyone care to reply?

Answer (score 0):

changing your register receiver to this will solve your problem.

this.registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter)